# ASP.NET and Access Databases

Tags: asp.net, ms-jet-ace

I have an ASP.NET web application that accesses an Access Database. The Access Database is only for testing purposes. I have hard coded the connection string which is correct, yet the application throws an error saying:

C:\MyDb\Db.mdb is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

My Connection String is:

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyDb\Db.mdb;

This is the correct path, why can't the developement server see the database? Do I have to configure it?

Please Help

Comment: This may sound like a silly question, but I have to ask. The MDB file is on the web server not your local hard drive. Right?

Answer (score 0):

See ['Not a valid path'](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167452) Error when Using Access Data Source, I think it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyDb\Db.mdb;Persist Security Info=True

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IIS? 
If so, does the IIS server have access to this file directory?

Comment: Have tried that, added the group Everyone with modify permissions, should be accessible to all now

Comment: JohnFx has a point. Is your Access db on the same machine as the IIS web server?

Comment: You also need to make sure that the IIS service user has rights to the file - which it may not by default if you put the database in the folder before you changed the access rights to the folder